# PHP $_GET['string'+$var] - Is this possible?

Tags: php

PHP Code so far.

```
echo $sender = isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : "null";
echo $receiver = isset($_GET['r']) ? $_GET['r'] : "null";
echo $timestamp = isset($_GET['t']) ? $_GET['t'] : "0";
echo "<br/>";
echo $sTotalItems = isset($_GET['si']) ? intval($_GET['si']) : 0;
echo $rTotalItems = isset($_GET['ri']) ? intval($_GET['ri']) : 0;
echo "<br/>";


for ($i = 0; $i < $sTotalItems; $i++) {
    echo $input = isset($_GET['si'+$i]) ? urldecode($_GET['si'+$i]) : "null";
    if ($input == "null")
        continue;

    $input = explode(":", $input);
    var_dump($input);

}
```

What I'm trying to do is dynamically grab a GET Variable. I'm sending multiple GET requests, and they all contain basically the same data, just small differences. - My question is simple though. This doesn't work like I'm thinkin it should in my mind.

```
$_GET['si'+$i];
```

In my mind, this should turn into..

```
$_GET['si1'];
```

Can this be done? Or am I going to have to figure out another way to do this? 
What this is doing.. is I'm sending multiple requests.. in the following order basically..

```
http://dummy.com/integrate.php?s=me&r=you&t=3425&si=1&ri=2&si0=item:1:2&ri0=item:2:1&ri1=item:3:4
```

I'm trying to make it dynamically possible, to send more than one "item," in which there is an identifier telling the system, how many items there are for each sender, and receiver. Then a loop goes through each sender & receivers' items, and then separates the item, into 3 values. the name, the id, and the amount. The problem, is the code, isn't grabbing the item at all. Am I correct, to assume, you can't use the $_GET method, and a variable together?

Comment: It is certainly possible. Go ahead and try it out - the array key index to `$_GET` just needs to be a string, and it doesn't matter whether that is a static string, a variable, a function call returning a string, whatever.

Comment: It is also possible, if you can change how the script's query string is passed, to pass variables as array structures, which is easier to deal with than things like `si0,si1`. Instead, as `si[0] si[1]`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Oh wait, now I see it. You're using `+` (addition), but you need to be using `.` for concatenation.  `'si' . $i` or `"si$i"`

Comment: haha, I just noticed the "+" too. I'm integrating PHP & a Java program.. the concatenation key always messes me up

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use dynamic variables along with `$_GET`, the only problem is use `.` (period) for concatenation not `+`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is loosely typed, so yes, you can "add" a number to a string and the number will be converted to its string representation for you. You use the concatenation operator (`.`) to do that, not the addition operator (`+`). Use `$_GET['si'.$i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show how to do what you are trying, however it's better to just use arrays.

Use `item[]=something&item[]=else` or even `item[1]=something&item[2]=else`.

Then you can access `$_GET['item'][0]` or `$_GET['item'][1]`, etc.